I train two multilayer perceptron for two target variables in the same dataset and the optimized hyperparameters seems to the same for both
I have a small dataset with about 210 data points for training with 5 input and 2 target parameters.
The dataset is about tile production, the input parameters are the production process parameters of the tiles and the output is the physical strength and water resistance of the tiles.
I am training two multilayer perceptrons for the two target parameters, but when I try to optimize the hyperparameters of the model with a random search, the optimal parameters found are the same for both models. I am using Scikit-learn and I am trying to optimize the number of hidden layers and nodes in the model, the solver algorithm used, the initial learning rate, and the regularization term.
I use the following code (I use the same parameters and code for both models, I just change the names of the variables where I store the found parameters and the output data used for fitting):

data_input_train = pd.read_csv("data_input_train.csv")
data_output_water_train = pd.read_csv('data_output_water_train.csv').values.ravel()

param_dist = {
    'hidden_layer_sizes': [(8, 5, 3), (10, 6, 4), (12, 8, 5), (10, 8, 5, 3), (12, 10, 6, 4), (14, 12, 8, 5)],
    'solver':['sgd', 'adam', 'lbfgs'],
    'alpha': uniform(0.0001, 0.1),  # Example range for regularization strength
    'learning_rate_init': uniform(0.001, 0.01),  # Example range for initial learning rate
}

model = MLPRegressor(random_state=42, max_iter=5000)

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(model, param_distributions=param_dist, n_iter=100, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', random_state=42)

random_search.fit(data_input_train, data_output_water_train)

best_params_MLP_water = random_search.best_params_

I double-checked to make sure I wasn't accidentally using the results from the other model, but that's not the problem.
These results would imply that the hyperparameters are independent of the target variable, which seems odd.
Is that a normal behavior for MLPs?
I'm not sure if the size of my data set or the parameters I'm testing are causing the problem.
I want to know if I'm missing something before I continue with my project.
